# Use different Angular 9 environment files when debugging in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have multiple Angular 9 environment.ts files that contain url´s for different servers that I am developing for e.g. prod, staging, dev, localhost. When I hit F5 the default environment.ts file is used which contains the localhost urls.

I want to be able to debug against my dev and staging servers, even prod when I hit F5. Is there an easy way to change which file is used when I hit F5 debug mode in VSCode?

Here is the launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your `launch.json` configuration?

Comment: Hi @Guillaume just added the file

Comment: Do you use `ng serve` to build and serve your app in dev mode ?

Comment: Hi @ThierryFalvo yes I am using ng serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch between your different environment files, with for example for your `staging` environment :

```sh
  ng serve --configuration staging
```